# How do I secure Azure Api Gateway with basic authentication

Tags: azure-api-management

I have a two micro-services. One is an authentication service and the other is a basic data fetching service. They are both setup in Azure Api Management.

I have all the users and passwords in my authentication services database and I simply want to use this information to secure the gateway and the data fetching service.

Does anyone know of any tutorials or good documentation to set this up as I can't find anything! I am very new to Azure.

I can obviously do this easily with a standard webservice but I can't see any way to secure the api gateway using my own table of user information.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the API’s from API management we can secure them by using subscription keys.

Usually, APIM will do the authorization and we need to enable the subscription.
Or we can even use client certificates that provides authentication between API and client.

Refer to this [blog](https://aztoso.com/apim/client-certificates-authentication/) for clear understanding and steps to secure our API’s, also we can do it with [Key vault](https://aztoso.com/posts/apim-basic-auth-keyvault/), thanks to AzToso for great explanation.

Comment: Did this answer resolve your problem?